# Как грамотно сверстать такой элемент

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]

Сложность вызвало именно вот это скругление, которое я указал на скриншоте.

Абсолютно спозиционировать png или есть другое решение?

Comment: можно с border radius поизвращаться попробовать

Comment: Я бы наверное png позиционировал бы и не парился...
Хотя наверняка можно чистым css сделать, но это не точно :-)

Answer (score 4):

Например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.s-1 {
  background: #2e3b4e;
  height: 200px;
}

.s-2 {
  height: 200px;
  background: #c35369 url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503455637927-730bce8583c0?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=7443420d1a52cdfe9f29d7e9f83a7796&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.separate svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -12px;
  margin-bottom: -22px;
}

.separate svg path{
  fill:#2e3b4e;
}
```

```html
<section class="s-1"></section>

  <div class="separate">
  
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 90 20" height="30" width="100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <path d="
               M 0,5
               C 25,5 25,20 45,20
               S 65,5 85,5
               z
               " />
    </svg>
</div>
  
<section class="s-2"></section>
```

- `M` - начальная точка, `X,Y`;
- `C` - кривая, `X1,Y1 X2,Y2 X,Y`;
- `S` - сглаживание `X2,Y2 X,Y`;
- `z` - замыкаем контур;

Подробнее об `svg path`:

1. [yoksel](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-path/)
2. [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/)

**P.S:** Этот пример svg взят с просторов сети, Вы же можете его сами нарисовать в редакторе (Illustrator) или так подкорректировать координаты.

Вот свой "язык" получилось сделать:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 50" height="50" width="100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="
             M 0,10
             C 20,10 20,50 50,50
             S 80,10 100,10
             z
             " />
  </svg>
```

Comment: Хороший, добротный ответ (+)

Comment: жесткий ты, в хорошем смысле! :D

Comment: Скажите, а как вы расчитали координаты элемента `<path>` в аттрибуте `d`? Я имею ввиду в данном случае `d="M0 5 H5 C25 5 25 20 45 20 S65 5 85 5 H90 V-5 H0z".`

Comment: @AntonOmelyanenko, обновила ответ

Answer (score 3):

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.foo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  left: -30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  background: #c5566c;
}

.foo__left,
.foo__right {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #c5566c;
}

.foo__left {
  left: -13px;
}

.foo__right {
  right: -13px
}

.foo__left:after,
.foo__right:after,
.foo__left:before,
.foo__right:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}

.foo__left:before,
.foo__left:after {
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.foo__right:before,
.foo__right:after {
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.foo__right:after {
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
}

.foo__left:after {
  top: 2px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seiqw.png />
<span class=foo>
<span class=foo__left></span>
<span class=foo__right></span>
</span>
```

Comment: kizoso, привет... мне кажется, лучше уж `svg` для этого...

Comment: @Air соглашусь)